# How do you share history between terminals in zsh?

Tags: command-line, history, zsh

How can it be achieved so that every command that is entered, is visible in every open terminal's history?

When having multiple terminals open, the history isn't shared, i.e. what you entered in one terminals history, doesn't show up in another one. Think of an alternative to Bash's  `PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a"` (which saves the history before the prompt is beeing displayed).

Comment: See also related and advanced Q&A: http://superuser.com/questions/446594/separate-up-arrow-lookback-for-local-and-global-zsh-history/691603#691603

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The following options would be applicable:

- To save every command before it is executed (this is different from bash's history -a solution):

  ```sh
  setopt inc_append_history
  ```
- To read the history file every time history is called upon, as well as the functionality from `inc_append_history`:

  ```sh
  setopt share_history
  ```

These can be set in your `.zshrc` file.

---

**⚠️ Either set `inc_append_history` or `share_history` but not both. (see comments below)**

- When `share_history` is enabled, it reads and writes to the history file.
- When `inc_append_history` is enabled, it only writes to the history file.

---

Related for bash: [Is it possible to make writing to .bash_history immediate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67283/is-it-possible-to-make-writing-to-bash-history-immediate)

Comment: "SHARE_HISTORY: This option both imports new commands from the history file, and also causes your typed commands to be appended to the history file (the latter is like specifying INC_APPEND_HISTORY, **which should be turned off if this option is in effect**)." (From [manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#History) emphasis added) i.e. just the INC_APPEND_HISTORY option will do what you want.

Comment: Actually, just the SHARE_HISTORY option alone will do what you want. The phrase "which should be turned off if this option is in effect" translates to "[INC_APPEND_HISTORY] should  be turned off if [SHARE_HISTORY] option is in effect". I've tested this on zsh 5.1.1 on Ubuntu Xenial.

Comment: @opert is correct: `setopt share_history` is what will accomplish the desired result.  @MJB would you be willing to edit your answer to remove the mention of `setopt inc_append_history`?  It obscures the actual answer.

Comment: [_Names are case insensitive and underscores are ignored_](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshoptions) so if you `setopt | grep hist` will get `incappendhistory` and `sharehistory`.

Comment: Just to clarify. You write command in shell 1, then switch to shell 2 and press enter. You will see that command as last only in case of `share_history`, but not `inc_append_history`.

Answer (score 8):

If you use Robby Russell’s awesome OhMyZSH, it will take care of this and more.

See https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/history.zsh

That includes `setopt inc_append_history`.

Comment: It's his/hers/its. Important for shell work.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman fixed, thank you. It's important for communication in general I believe. What did you mean by "Important for shell work"?

Comment: A typo in the shell can corrupt your entire system.

Comment: should I paste it into `.zshrc`?