# How to get all shell command logged

Tags: log, rsyslog

I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.04, and trying to get all Shell command logged.
I'm trying with `rsyslog` that there by default.
I added "`*.* /var/log/everything.log`" in `rsyslog.con`f and `50-default.conf`, but I'm only getting few entries(login,logout, service stop/start) and would like to have everything `ls, cd [path], [Wrong command]`.

Do I have to modify something in rsyslog or setting any other application to verbose.

Thx
SP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to using `bash_history`, to capture every command entered in the shell by **yourself** and save it to file you could use something like the `trap` command in a script or function and place that code in `.bashrc`.

Fortunately,  **exactly** the script you want was provided by [Richard Hansen](https://askubuntu.com/users/19996/richard-hansen) a while ago [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160745/how-to-find-history-of-shell-commands-since-machine-was-created/162643#162643), and his script copies every command entered into bash  and sends them (with a timestamp) to a file called `.command_log` by default. Once you have placed his script into your `.bashrc` and have launched terminal, Richard's script writes the commands to `.command_log` as soon as they are executed, unlike the `bash_history` feature, which only writes to the file after the terminal is closed.

Richard's script will record your commands like this in `.command_log` (although you will be using different commands to me):

```
2012-10-02T18:02:11+0100 /dev/pts/2 gksudo truecrypt
2012-10-02T21:52:03+0100 /dev/pts/2 xrandr -s 1280x1024
2012-10-03T00:16:52+0100 /dev/pts/2 mount
2012-10-03T00:17:12+0100 /dev/pts/2 udisks --unmount /dev/sdb1
2012-10-03T00:17:46+0100 /dev/pts/2 udisks --detach /dev/sdb
```

I have been using it for a while and find that Richard's script is very useful; you can even `grep` the `.command_log` and search for anything you want:

```
grep -i udisks .command_log
```

So, I think this is probably what you want if you need to record every single thing typed into bash; I find it incredibly useful.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you want to do. If you want to monitor all what users run, then no, this is not easily possible. There is an administrative suite of programs called [bos](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/bos.8.html) which can be used to monitor all running processes.

If, however, you just want to store all commands that *you* type, then yes, this is being done for you by bash. Bash stores a command history in `~/.bash_history`.  By default, however, only when a shell exits the command history is written. Read [this](http://blog.tonyscelfo.com/2009/04/save-all-of-your-bash-history.html) web page if you want to customize it such that most of your history is saved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a entire session logged (ie. both commands typed AND results from those commands) use:

`script`

Without arguments, it will save the results to a file in the current directory called "typescript".

`script bogus.txt` will save to "bogus.txt"

See man page for complete list of commands 
`man script`