# Is it possible to track the terminal command of a user

Tags: 14.04, server, bash, bash-history

We want to monitor the user typing command using terminal .
Where the command is saving (.bash-history) is only showing few of the command.
Is it possible to get the command executed from the beginning

Comment: Check this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/160745/how-to-find-history-of-shell-commands-since-machine-was-created

Comment: There are several options, but I am going to guess they are somewhat off topic. You can try a key logger (probably best), pam, write a script ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698590/how-to-capture-all-the-commands-typed-in-unix-linux-by-any-user and http://serverfault.com/questions/336217/how-do-i-log-every-command-executed-by-a-user and and http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-monitor-keyboard-keystrokes-using-logkeys-in-linux/ and google search ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the bash history size. Basically you can increase it to unlimited.

```
export HISTSIZE=
export HISTFILESIZE=
```

The above lines can be added in `~/.bashrc` of the user or `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: If a user starts their command with a space history will ignore it by default.

Comment: is bashrc-history the only file that records the commands ?

Comment: @errakesh this is correct.

Comment: Note that a user can remove commands from history if he/she wants to.
See https://superuser.com/questions/525839/how-to-prevent-a-user-from-hiding-their-bash-history and https://askubuntu.com/questions/657286/how-to-prevent-commands-being-removed-from-history.