# Slow terminal commands

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, git

I'm facing a weird problem that I never had in 4 years using Ubuntu.

Commands in the terminal are running very slowly. A simple `clear` takes up to 20 seconds, as well as `cd`, get into `vim`, everything is really. Sometimes it even freezes the input to the point that I can't type anything for a long time.

I'm currently using Ubuntu 20.04.

I have no idea what could be causing this weird behavior. Can someone shed some light on it?

UPDATE:
[Htop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWIWO.png)

UPDATE 2:

[image: htop screenshot CPU usage high]

This shows the CPU usage on its way to 100%, and I found out that this behavior only happens in a specific git repository once I cd in it. I've run `git status` with some flags and it is using 100% CPU. But the diff is really small. Other git repos in my machine work fine.

Comment: I suggest that you use a system monitoring tool like `htop` to gather information about a possible source of your issue

Comment: @Nmath I added a screenshot of htop output. Memory consumption is high, but I'm running an Android emulator, spotify, 10+ tabs in firefox, and development server locally so is expected to be that high. Anyway I still have around 7gb ram left

Comment: The idea is that you keep it up and pay close attention especially when your system comes to a crawl.  You're not close to using the limit on your RAM or CPU processes *at this snapshot of time*.   Also, these slow terminal commands, are they happening over a network like when you use SSH? Because you're affected by ping/latency in these situations

Comment: Sounds more related to some attached (network) drives that your system waits for.

Comment: @Nmath I'm running all these commands on my machine. No ssh connections

Comment: @pLumo can you give an example? Not sure I get it

Comment: @Nmath update de post. I belive that could be git related

Comment: I'd investigate whatever it is that you use `git` for.  AFAIK it shouldn't be active unless you use it and have scheduled some task.

Comment: Probably is oh-my-zsh triggering git when I cd in a git folder, so it can show the branch and other information in the status bar

Answer (score 2):

> I'm facing a weird problem that I never had in 4 years using in Ubuntu.

And more than two years later, I faced the exact same problem :') Same Ubuntu version.

It happened only in one of my project folders for me. `htop` showed high CPU usage. Every symptom you had checked out with me.

After some experimentation, I found out that in my case clearing my `.bash_history` fixed it. I further removed some customisation in my `.bashrc` to prevent it from happening in future.

I had `PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;$PROMPT_COMMAND"` in my `.bashrc` because I wanted my history to instantly update after each run command in my shell (via [Is it possible to make writing to .bash_history immediate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67283/)). Been using that for years but I removed that line. So my Bash history limit was also set to high and had been collecting everything since then.

I also suspect that duplicate entries were being put in it as well since that's the default. I then added the `ignoredups` in my `rc` file to disable duplicate entries.  I'm assuming that large history + the `.bashrc` customisation didn't go well with my Git repo.

Numerous factors are probably at work here. I can only speculate what caused this weird behaviour being a novice but what I can confirm is that this *solved* my problem. I hope that offhand chance this fix can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I tried many solutions available on the internet but nothing worked. but upgrating packages has solved problem quickly.

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt upgrade`
3. restart the terminal.

Thank you.