# Save a command in the terminal

Tags: networking, openstack

I installed OpenStack and then I shutdown the laptop. After turning on the laptop again I can't enter the programmer.

How can I save my work in Ubuntu?

Comment: Please add more details to your question like which command you ran to install and what is the error message you are getting now.

Comment: What program do you want to enter ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View history of commands ran in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624848/view-history-of-commands-ran-in-terminal) and [How to save terminal history manually?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261407/how-to-save-terminal-history-manually)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `history` command to see commands you have recently used.

Comment: Please show examples of how to use this command!

Comment: you can use this command like this : histroy | grep '(type here which command you want to use ) '

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice file named .bashrc.
It is located in your home folder.

At the bottom you can save commands in it. 
This is a example:

```
alias mci='mvn clean install'
```

When I write mci I really am writing mvn clean install.

If you write history in terminal you get a print out of .bash_history file. Also located in your home folder.